# Masking in World Space canvas - Gameobject renderers act as mask too

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

My goal was to create a Scroll Rect on a worldspace canvas but whenever I would mask out the content everything vanished. I tested on an overlay canvas to see if I was setting it up correctly and I was.

What I learned was that non-UI gameobject renderers were being used as the mask too so if there was something being rendered in world space, it would mask the Scroll Rect Content.

The top image shows the mask disabled. The bottom shows the mask enabled.

Any ideas how I can have it ignore the worldspace objects?!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is an answer but changing the main camera from Deferred rendering to Forward will fix this.