# Unity 4.6 UGUI Mask in Worldspace Canvas

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine, mask, unity3d-gui

I am trying to create a UGUI Mask using a Canvas rendering in Worldspace. I am using Unity v4.6.1f1. Any world geometry in the scene masks the image even when the Canvas and all of its children are on the UI layer and the camera is rendering Forward.

Very similar to the problem listed here: [Masking in World Space canvas - Gameobject renderers act as mask too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348840/masking-in-world-space-canvas-gameobject-renderers-act-as-mask-too)

however, as was mentioned previously, having the camera render Forward instead of Deferred doesn't have any effect.

Moving the canvas into world space where there is no world geometry results in the mask and masked image to work as intended.

I'm looking for a fix where I can have the canvas in worldspace in front of world geometry, but have the mask only affected by the image I set on the canvas and not the surrounding world geometry.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the the problem was with the Unity player settings.  Though the player settings were set to forward rendering and the camera in use was set to use those player settings, it appeared that the camera was not using forward rendering.  Changing the actual camera in the scene to use forward rendering manually resolved the issue.